# Generate file when installing extension

Tags: magento2, code-generation, integration

I want to create an **xml** file when I first install the integration in `/app/code/Foo/Bar/view/frontend/layout` with php.

Is it possible to do so and how should it be done ? Tried with fopen in `InstallData.php` but it did not create the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this in the `InstallData.php` file.
make the constructor look like this:

```
private $io;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File $io,
    ....
) {
    $this->io = $io;
    ....
}
```

Then, in the install method run this:

```
$filePath = 'relative/path/to/file';
$file = 'somefile.xml';
$content = 'your content here';
$fileMetaData = $this->io->getPathInfo($filePath.'/'.$file);
$this->io->mkdir($fileMetaData['dirname']);
$this->io->write($filePath.'/'.$file, $content, 0777);
```